# What kind of creature was the first movie monster to be described as "Undead"?

Tags: movie, history-of, origins

The undead are everywhere. Vampires. Werewolves. Zombies. <strike>Frankensteins Monster</strike>. (Edit- OK. According to Dr. Frankenstein "[It's Alive!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xos2MnVxe-c)") What kind of creature was the first movie monster to be described as "*Undead*", and what was the name of the film it appeared in?

Comment: I don't think Werewolves are actually undead...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto Some are, some aren't, that depends on the mythos.

Comment: @Gilles pic (or reference as the case may be) or it didn't happen. I am not too familiary with werewolves but all I saw were actual living.

Comment: @DVK Most traditional werewolves are part man part wolf part monster, not undead. But some werewolves are not killable by ordinary means, making them not exactly alive; in particular [the traditions where vampires and werewolves are similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werewolf#Vampiric_connections) (a connection which has become more common in the 20th century).

Comment: "Not killable by ordinary means" would make Achilles and the Hulk undead too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***TL;DR:***

- Earliest *All-around possible*:

  **(1909)** ***The Mummy of King Ramses (France)***

  It's not clear if the Mummy was actually undead! So I'm skeptical.
- Earliest *All-around definite undead*:

  **(1910)** ***[Frankenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein_%281910_film%29)***
- Earliest *Vampire (possible)*

  **(1916)** ***[A Night of Horror/Nächte des Grauens)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Night_of_Horror)***
- Earliest *Appearance of Dracula*

  **(1921)** ***Drakula halála/The Death of Dracula]***
- Earliest *Full-length vampire movie to survive*:

  **(1922)** ***Nosferatu, eine Symphonie des Grauens***
- Earliest *Someone pretending to be a vampire*:

  **(1927)** ***London After Midnight***
- Earliest undead (non-somnabula) *Zombie*:

  **(1932)** ***[Victor Halperin's White Zombie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zombie_films)***

---

---

---

---

---

***DETAILS AND SOURCES:***

Here are some of the earliest ones, scavenged together from 3 sources:

- A book ***In Search of Dracula: The History of Dracula and Vampire***s By Raymond T. McNally, Radu Florescu (Listed as "McNally" in sources and available from [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=P22TnNTonYwC&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=%22The%20Vampire%27s%20Trail%22&source=bl&ots=hyZB41rhr9&sig=6B65JppXxuOu-lkoHO3ut6DJi1g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EDkBUNOhN-Wn6AHKvLCBBw&ved=0CHgQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20Vampire%27s%20Trail%22&f=false))
- Several Wiki articles
- A site http://monsterkidclassichorrorforum.yuku.com

---

---

> - Most of the early, and by now obscure, silent films about vampires are mostly about "vamps" — female flirts who entice or captivate men.
> - **The earliest full-length vampire movie to survive** is ***F. W. Murnau's classic silent film Nosferatu (1922)***, which was based on Stoker's novel Dracula (1897). (src: *McNally*)

To give slightly more details on *Nosferatu*, due to its prominence:

> **Nosferatu, eine Symphonie des Grauens** (translated as Nosferatu: A Symphony of Horror; or simply Nosferatu) is a classic **1922** German Expressionist horror film, directed by F. W. Murnau, starring Max Schreck as the vampire Count Orlok. The film, shot in 1921 and released in 1922, was an unauthorized adaptation of Bram Stoker's Dracula (src: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosferatu))

---

---

Please note that [Nosferatu is not the first Vampire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_film) in film, BUT most of the earlier ones (like "*The Vampire*") were NOT about the undead - some were about criminals, and most - like the titular 1910 one - were about female Vamp who stole someone's husband, as noted in the *McNally* quote above.

---

---

However, there seemingly WERE earlier undead movies.

From http://monsterkidclassichorrorforum.yuku.com/topic/34371/The-Vampire-of-the-Coast-1909#.UAE025hoKsc:

> - One of the earliest may be ***Nächte des Grauens (1916) (aka Night of Horror)***, a German film. Unfortunately not much is to be found online about it, but it is listed in The Vampire Book (Encyclopedia of the Undead).
> - Another is ***Drakula halála [aka The Death of Dracula] from 1921*** (directed by Károly Lajthay)-Hungarian". The film is about a woman who experiences frightening visions after visiting an insane asylum where one of the inmates claims to be Count Dracula, and she has trouble determining if the visions were real or merely nightmares".
>     [ NOTE: Wiki adds: "Unlicensed Hungarian adaptation. **First known film appearance of Dracula**. This film has been lost since its release ].
> - One of the earliest **fake vampires** was in ***London After Midnight (1927)*** by Todd Browning (yes, him), starring Lon Chaney. The vampire in it is actually a detective trying to scare a confession out of some criminals, but the makeup is legendary. That one was lost to a fire. This is a [short documentary](http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&v=MeqZtkRbvP0) about it.
> - The famous ***Nosferatu, eine Symphonie des Grauens of 1922***, is probably the oldest you can still see.

If you take zombies, [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zombie_films) sez:

> ***Victor Halperin's White Zombie was released in 1932*** and is often cited to be the first zombie film.

If you count Frankenstein:

> ***Frankenstein is a 1910*** film made by Edison Studios that was written and directed by J. Searle Dawley. It was the first motion picture adaptation of Mary Shelley's Frankenstein. (src: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein_%281910_film%29))

Comment: Frankenstein wasn't undead by any stretch of the word. In the novel, definitely a typical homunculus (not even really created from mad science, so much as it leaves the impression of alchemy). In the movie it's little different. He doesn't feed off the living. Doesn't exist to harass the living or promote his blasphemous existence. Wasn't raised by a necromancer. In this particular movie, it harkens back to the homunculus origins of the novel, and not to the reanimated mad science corpse of later movies. You might as well call Godzilla undead, if this counts. And yet my comment gets deleted.

Comment: @JohnO - Frankensteins Monster (as far as I recall, Frankenstein was the creator) is considered undead because the OP included him in the undead list in the question. Otherwise I might have hesitated to.

Comment: The OP is wrong. If he had included Ironman in the list, would Tony Stark be undead too?

Comment: [It does seem that Ramses's mummy was animated in the 1909 movie.](http://www.classichorror.free-online.co.uk/mar.htm#roi) But [Cleopatra](http://www.imdb.com/news/ni0101658/) predated him by 8 years.

Comment: @JohnO OK. Said its physician to his assistant: "It's Alive!", so you are correct. Frankensteins Monster shouldn't be called undead. Tony Stark can't play because he would be considered as "not dead yet."

Comment: I think the relevant point here, based on the OP's question, is "did anyone *in that movie* describe the monster as undead"?

Comment: also, not that this is authoritative in any way, but from Wikipedia: "Frankenstein by Mary Shelley is a seminal text in 19th century discourse about the undead".

Comment: Way late, but was the creature not stitched together corpses scientifically/alchemically animated? Out of curiosity, would animated dead flesh not count as undead, as the creature is literally the walking dead (flesh)?

Comment: Great question @MajorStackings and _fantastic_ answer DVK!

Answer (score 5):

### What kind of creature was the first movie monster to be described as “Undead”?

I'm answering this question from another angle and looking for contemporary descriptions.

Searching [Subzin](http://www.subzin.com/search.php?title=&imdb=&q=undead&search_sort=Oldest&genre=-1&type=All) for films that actually use the word "undead", the earliest I found is 
*Dracula* (1931) starring Bela Lugosi:

- 00:31:47 "... we are dealing with the undead."
- 00:31:57 "... the undead, the vampire."
- 00:54:46 "... but an undead creature whose life has been unnaturally prolonged."

This film was also referred to Dracula as undead in its contemporary marketing materials, according to the *[Motion Picture Herald](http://books.google.fi/books?id=XAcdAQAAMAAJ&q=undead%20FILM&dq=undead%20FILM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jgoDUNigDKap4gSezPSqCA&redir_esc=y)* (1931):

> The copy read "Dracula — Mighty Monarch of the Undead Creatures of Darkness — Leaves His Earth Home Between Noon and Midnight to Appear at the (theatre, playdate).

Comment: That's an angle on the question I didn't consider. +1

Answer (score 4):

There were many films featuring undead creatures in the silent era. As these films used few word, it is likely that it took a while until the word *undead* itself was used. The first undead in films predate title cards.

The word *undead* was introduced in its modern sense by [Bram Stoker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bram_Stoker) in [*Dracula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula), in the very early days of the movie era (1897). Before, the word simply meant *not dead*, i.e. *alive*.

[Georges Méliès](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_M%C3%A9li%C3%A8s), arguably the first fiction filmmaker, made several films on science fiction, fantasy and horror themes. [*Le Manoir du Diable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Haunted_Castle_%281896_film%29) (*The Devil's Manor*, also known as *The Haunted Castle*), shot in 1896, is one of the earliest fiction films and probably the first horror and fantasy movie. It opens with a bat turning into a man — or perhaps a devil in the form of a man (not a vampire: before *Dracula*, the association between vampires and bats was not so common in popular fiction). The man conjures several fantastical creatures out of a cauldron, including figures in white robes who are indubitably ghosts. The film is in the public domain and [available online](http://archive.org/details/LeChteauHante).

Another early series of films that may feature ghosts is the early adaptation of [*Rip Van Winkle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_Van_Winkle) by  [W.K.L. Dickson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_K.L._Dickson) with [Joseph Jefferson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Jefferson). The films were produced in 1896, and I believe that Hudson and crew in *Rip's Toast to Hudson and Crew* are supposed to be ghosts.

Another first worth mentioning is the first adaptation of Charles Dickens's [*A Christmas Carol*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Carol): [*Scrooge, or, Marley's Ghost*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrooge,_or,_Marley%27s_Ghost), directed by [Walter R. Booth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_R._Booth) in 1901. This film (mostly lost) features Marley's ghost. Also in 1901, [*The Haunted Curiosity Shop*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0000357/) by Robert W. Paul depicted a ghost and other supernatural events.

The first mummy brought to life that I could uncover is Cleopatra in Georges Méliès's [*Cléopâtre*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cl%C3%A9op%C3%A2tre_%281899_film%29), filmed in 1899. The two-minute film shows Cleopatra rising from her grave. Although the film, long believed lost, was [recently found](http://www.imdb.com/news/ni0101658/), I could not find a copy online.

Ordinary reanimated corpses were not common in western fiction until much later, when Haitian voodoo myths became popular in the United States. The movie that started the genre (which was to be redefined by [Georges Romero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_A._Romero) 40 years later) is [*White Zombie*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Zombie_%28film%29) by [Victor Halperin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Halperin) (1932).

Turning to vampires, Bram Stoker's novel did not lead to a movie adaptation for several decades. Early big screen “vampires” were in fact female sexual predators — vamps, not undead. The first unambiguous vampire movie (in the undead sense of the word) was [*Dracula's Death*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula%27s_Death) (*Drakula halála*), a 1921 Hungarian movie by [Károly Lajthay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1roly_Lajthay), now lost. (There may have been [a Russian movie called *Dracula* the year before](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drakula_%281920_film%29#Early_adaptations), but the evidence of its existence is scarce.) The Hungarian movie predated Murnau's famous [*Nosferatu*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosferatu) by a few months. You can read more in
[Robert Hood's article on early vampire cinema](http://roberthood.net/blog/index.php/2010/08/08/early-vampire-cinema-from-1916-to-1974-part-1/).

Comment: +1 but please bold out Cleopatre - that seems to be the best contender for an actual answer. Ghosts aren't undead, I would think

Comment: @DVK Some definitions require undead to be corporeal, some include any spirit living on after dead even if disembodied. For example, D&D classifies ghosts as undead. It's unclear to me whether the ghosts in *Le Manoir du Diable* are corporeal; the ones in *Rip van Winkle* are, since they hand the titular character a drink.

Comment: I don't think that D&D is a good authority here. That sort of game requires that the authors categorize everything, even for those things which defy categorization. However, ghosts do share at least some of the attributes of the undead: they're subject to the rules of religious artifacts and rituals (notably exorcism) that vampires and zombies are limited by. They do exist after the death of the person they resemble. They harass the living, make a mockery of life, etc. On the other hand, I think that any word association test would find them unlinked in the minds of the typical person.

Comment: Ghosts are just dead, not undead.

Comment: @Oldcat I don't doubt that someone somewhere has created a fantasy world where ghosts are not undead. But under the usual meaning of the word, they are. Undead typically covers any sentient entity that was once alive and has become supernatural and no longer subject to dying.

Comment: They are non-corporeal spirits, not alive like they used to be. There are spirits that were never human.  D&D goofball classifications aside for the turn undead spell. Ghosts don't have to be evil.